# Countif with multiple criteria based on date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have difficulties with the following scenario.

I need to get the amount (count) of the product ordered in a specific time range (today + 8 days back).

- Column [A] consists of the order date.
- Column [B] conssists of the product being ordered.
- Column [C] should give me the amount ordered within the last 8 days.
- Column [D] is my current result.

[image]

The problem is that the results in column [D] are wrong according to my need. In row 7 you can see that this product was ordered twice in the last 8 days, but this is wrong.

Second example (colored orange) is correct, but only because both dates are within the range of past 8 days.

My current formula in column [D] is:

```
=IF(A2>=TODAY()-8,COUNTIF(B$2:B$10,B2),"")
```

I think it's not possible to use COUNTIFS (multiple criteria) in combination with the date restriction, right?
What is the correct approach for this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use a formula in the criteria, The range part has to be a range not an array.

```
COUNTIFS(B$2:B$10,B2,$A$2:$A$10,">="&TODAY()-8)
```

So:

```
=IF(A2>=TODAY()-8,COUNTIFS(B$2:B$10,B2,$A$2:$A$10,">="&TODAY()-8),"")
```

Comment: perfect! the second solution suits my case better, because it leaves the cell blank instead putting in a zero.

Comment: The first was just the part to show how to do it.  The second is the actual formula, hence the missing `=` in the first one.

Comment: some results show "0". it only happens to order dates from yesterday and today. Any idea why? Does the formula include today and yesterday? edit: dates are not necessarily sorted.

Comment: check to ensure those dates are true dates and not strings that look like dates.

Comment: my bad. when extend the rows by adding new orders, I will have to adjust the formula accordingly! I might just put "5000" instead of "10" to the formula, or is there a better way?

Comment: You can use a table and then use structured references.  But if your data will never exceed 5000 then that approach is the easiest.